# Android progress dialog without using Threads

Tags: android, progressdialog

Is it possible to get a progress dialog (a "loading..." one, not a percentual one) without using threads? I would even accept a custom dialog with an static image instead of the loading animation. So, is it possible? How?

Comment: Do you still need to load data, or are you just throwing a loading bar in for the hell of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible.

I would recomend using [an AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is what the Android Team made to simplify threading.

Comment: IS it possible to run the progressDialog with the AsyncTask (or even a Thread) and tell it when to dismiss, instead of the natural behaviour, which would be making a thread/AsyncTask for the task? That would fit for me too

Comment: No. Do you need to show a ProgressDialog because you are loading something?

Comment: I am waiting a download to be finished. User won't be able to do anything until it is finished. I just want to show something to tell him "Please wait"

Comment: You need to use async task, there is no other way. Its really easy to use.

Comment: It is, but I'm afraid the code don't work anymore if I make such a change, because the main thread is dessigned to do the duty instead of creating a thread for that. Why can't it be the opposite anyway? Why can't you create the thread for the animation?

Comment: The main thread handles the UI, heavy work should be done on background threads so that the UI remains active. Doing heavy work on the main thread will block the UI, if it takes more that 5 secs it will also bring up a non-responsive dialog.